# Dataframe. Need to Count the total number of different people each week (7 days). python

Tags: python, dataframe

Have a dataframe with name and dates. Need to Count the total number of different people each week (7 days).
My dataframe is :

```
GREGO,NAME
12-29,CHERI
12-30,AMANDA
12-30,Mitchell
12-31,AMANDA
12-31,ERICA
12-31,Melanie
1-1,AMANDA
1-1,ERICA
1-1,Melanie
1-2,ERICA
1-2,RAYMOND
1-2,Helen
1-3,OSCAR
1-3,RACHEL
1-3,Helen
1-4,JANE
1-4,RACHEL
1-4,Helen
1-5,AMY
1-5,JANE
1-5,RACHEL
```

Result:

```
GREGO,TOTALWEEK
1-4,10
1-5,10
1-6 ...etc
```

thank you

Comment: Please read the Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct  and provide evidence of what you have tried so far an failed .We are here to help you solve your problems so. What has been your problem so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just group them together and count them.

```
df.set_index('GREGO',inplace=True)    
df.groupby(level=0).resample('W').count()


NAME
GREGO   GREGO   
01-01   01-07   3
01-02   01-07   3
01-03   01-07   3
01-04   01-07   3
01-05   01-07   2
12-29   12-30   1
12-30   12-30   2
12-31   01-06   3
```